# Viewpager2 scroll stops working when scrolling back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I am facing a weird issue, I have a Viewpager2, the fragment page contains a Scrollview, HorizontalScrollView, and a RecyclerView.

When I launch the fragment that hosts the ViewPager the UI works, it also works if I swipe right, but as soon as I swipe left to the previous page the touch stops working, I lose the ability to swipe up and down on the page.

I feel lost here, it worked perfectly fine with the old ViewPager

**ViewPager fragment page**

```
<ScrollView
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="true"
    android:background="?backgroundColor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 <ScrollView/>
```

**ViewPager**

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        ...
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating ViewPager's PageTransformer.

I extended `ViewPager2.PageTransformer` on my PageTransformer thinking the old transformer would work just fine.

Looks like this is not the case, the old version was missing the `translationZ` looks like not setting the `translationZ` causes this behavior.